# Not all "properties" of user-defined-type is being accepted

Tags: sql, plsql, record

So i've had this error in which i created a type

```
type TeamLeagueStats is record(
        teamId TEAM.TEAMID%type,
        teamName TEAM.TEAMNAME%type,
        wins NUMBER,
        losses NUMBER,
        draws NUMBER,
        points NUMBER,
        matchesPlayed NUMBER
    );
```

And this type is inside my package-header

But this Type will only partially work inside my package-body

```
teamLeagueStats_P.TEAMID := TEAM_API.REQUEST_TEAM(teamId_P).TEAMID;
teamLeagueStats_P.TEAMNAME := TEAM_API.REQUEST_TEAM(teamId_P).TEAMNAME;
```

the property "teamname" isnt accepted by the record, but the teamId is?

Ice tried asking ChatGPT, research for similar problems, but ive found nothing

Comment: "but the teamId is" >> how do you know? What happens if you comment (i.e. *remove*) the 2nd line (this: `teamLeagueStats_P.TEAMNAME := ...`). Is teamId still accepted? Consider posting some more code which can be executed on our side so that we'd see what you exactly did and how Oracle exactly responded, because "property is not being accepted" isn't very descriptive.